# Mapping exception in RxJava 2

Tags: java, exception, reactive-programming, rx-java2

How can I map one occurred exception to another one in RxJava2? 
For example:

```
doOnError(throwable -> {
    if (throwable instanceof FooException) {
        throw new BarException();
    }
})
```

In this case I finally receive `CompositeException` that consists of `FooException` and `BarException`, but I'd like to receive only `BarException`. Help!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use onErrorResumeNext and return Observable.error() from it:

```
source.onErrorResumeNext(e -> Observable.error(new BarException()))
```

**Edit**

This test passes for me:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Observable.error(new IOException())
    .onErrorResumeNext((Throwable e) -> Observable.error(new IllegalArgumentException()))
    .test()
    .assertFailure(IllegalArgumentException.class);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work and gives the same result as using `doOnError`

Comment: I've updated my answer with an unit test demonstrating such replacement works.